# In windows XP how to get back my profile?

Tags: windows-xp, restore, user-profiles

I have a windows XP machine with split drives:

C:\ - just OS
D:\ - my data

I ran out of disk space and when logging into my profile, it popped with some error stating that since it didn't have any disk space it was logging me in as some default profile (even thought i was logging into my account name that i always use so it wasn't complete corrupted)

I deleted a bunch of files to get some space but now when i log into my account, all of my desktop icons are missing and when i click on "My Documents" it takes me to some new folder on the C:\ drive.

When i try to change to target of My documents to D:\My Documents i get an error that looks like this:

[image]

Can anyone give me some advice on how to restore my profile (as even though i am logging in to the same name on the main Windows XP login screen, it doesn't seem associated with all my stuff) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error Message: Windows Cannot Load Your Profile Because It May Be Corrupted  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318011

Create a New User or Restore the User Profile
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811151

### Create a new user profile on the workgroup computer

1. Log on as the Administrator or as a user with administrator credentials.
2. Click **Start**, and then click **Control Panel**.
3. Click **User Accounts**.
4. Under **Pick a task**, click **Create a new account**.
5. Type a name for the user information, and then click **Next**.
6. Click an account type, and then click **Create Account**.

### Copy files to the new user profile

1. Log on as a user other than the user whose profile you are copying files to or from.
2. In Windows Explorer, click **Tools**, click **Folder Options**, click the **View** tab, click **Show hidden files and folders**, click to clear the **Hide protected operating system files** check box, and then click **OK**.
3. Locate the C:\Documents and Settings\Old_Username folder, where C is the drive on which Windows XP is installed, and Old_Username is the name of the profile you want to copy user data from.
4. Press and hold down the CTRL key while you click each file and subfolder in this folder, except the following files:
   Ntuser.dat
   Ntuser.dat.log
   Ntuser.ini
5. On the **Edit** menu, click **Copy**.
6. Locate the C:\Documents and Settings\New_Username folder, where C is the drive on which Windows XP is installed, and New_Username is the name of the user profile that you created in the "Create a New User Profile" section.
7. On the **Edit** menu, click **Paste**.
8. Log off the computer, and then log on as the new user.

Note You must import your e-mail messages and addresses to the new user profile before you delete the old profile. For more information, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
[313055](http://support.microcenter.com/kb/313055)  Mail folders, address book, and e-mail messages are missing after you upgrade to Microsoft Windows XP

Source:
http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/57376-45-local-profiles-unavailable-loading-temp-profile

Another option is to try the TweakUI tool:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/c/a/fca6767b-9ed9-45a6-b352-839afb2a2679/TweakUiPowertoySetup.exe